# SharePoint Online - Search Update, missing people filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, people-search

Does anyone have any information on this latest update? The people filter is missing from the search[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the modern search results page (`/_layouts/15/search.aspx/`) on the `'A' Street` site scope. The site scope search does not provide the way to filter people, similar to the classic OOB site search results page (`/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx`).

[image]

You need to click “**SharePoint**”, as shown in the image below, to search everything in SharePoint.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to default that for all users? This workaround isn't very intuitive

Comment: It is by design. Be default, it will search in site scope first. The workaround is to use the classic search within search center site, refer to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-the-search-center-in-sharepoint-online-174d36e0-2f85-461a-ad9a-8b3f434a4213